# Magento 2 - checkout_submit_all_after event is not working

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer

In Magento, I have to get order items in the observer.

I am trying two method `sales_order_place_after` and `checkout_submit_all_after`.

Both events is not working.

**events.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_cart_product_add_after">
        <observer name="cart_product" instance="Example\Details\Observer\CartProduct" />
    </event>
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="oreder_item" instance="Example\Details\Observer\OrderItem" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**OrderItem.php**

```
<?php

namespace Example\Details\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class OrderItem implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
        $this->_objectManager = $objectManager;
    }

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $orderItems = $observer->getOrder();
        $orderItems->getEntityId();
    }
}
```

I use both conditions one by one but it's not working.

Comment: From your above code how can you tell that it is not working? Have you tried putting logging in the class?

Comment: @Smartie i am enter order id in my custom module but its not working

Comment: Where exactly did you put the `events.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<event name="checkout_onepage_controller_success_action">
        <observer name="after_place_order" instance="namespace\module\model\Observer"/>
    </event>
```

in obsereve

```
<?php
namespace namespace\module\model\Observer;


use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository;

class Observer implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface {


    protected $orderRepository;
    protected $ProductRepository;
    protected $customerSession;

    public function __construct(  

    OrderRepositoryInterface $OrderRepositoryInterface,
    ProductRepository $ProductRepository,
    \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
    ) {
        $this->orderRepository = $OrderRepositoryInterface;
        $this->ProductRepository =$ProductRepository;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;

    }
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer ) {        

        $order_ids = $observer->getEvent()->getOrderIds()[0];

        $order = $this->orderRepository->get($order_ids);
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            //code here
            }

}
```

Comment: hi @sagar Dobariya let me know how can save custom field data here? could u tell me thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need to change any event just adds the log in the execution file.   Like this.

Event.xml

```
<event name="sales_order_place_after">
    <observer name="oreder_item" instance="Example\Details\Observer\OrderItem" / >
</event>
```

And your Observer add the log like this.
OrderItem.php

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    $orderId = $order->getId();

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testingObserver.log');

    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();

    $logger->addWriter($writer);

    $logger->info($orderId."OrderId");

}
```

After placing the order please checks your log you will see the order ID.

```
Kay K
https://www.aspirationhosting.com
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below code.

please create events.xml in etc folder.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="after_order_place" instance="Vender\Module\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter" />
    </event>
</config>
```

please create OrderPlaceAfter.php class in Observer folder

> Path:- Vender\Module\Observer\OrderPlaceAfter.php

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Observer;


use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
class OrderPlaceAfter implements ObserverInterface
{
    
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        // your code
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your way of implementation is wrong. You need to observe the event under your module's config.xml file. As mentioned below,

Under your module `etc/config.xml`

```
<frontend>
...
 <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <mobileapp_clearcart_after_weborder>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>NAMESPACE_MODULE_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>getorderDetails</method>
                </mobileapp_clearcart_after_weborder>
            </observers>                
        </sales_order_place_after>
...
</frontend>
```

Under `Model/Observer.php`

```
class NAMESPACE_MODULE_Model_Observer {

    public function getorderDetails($observer){
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();     
        $billing = $order->getBillingAddress();
        $shipping = $order->getShippingAddress();
        $customer = $order->getCustomer();         
        $order_id = $order->getIncrementId();
        $customer_id = $order->getCustomerId();         
        return true;
    }

}
```

Replace NAMESPACE with your Package name and MODULE with your Module name.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Question is about "Magento 2". Are you sure this method is still valid ?

Comment: @Prateek No it wont. I didn't see the magento2 tag.

Comment: @Vinoth I am using Magento 1, how to print what event using in observer and print into log-file, just print event in log-file, how can i do that?