# Magento 2 - checkout_submit_all_after event is not working after checkout completion

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, payment-methods

I have need to get Order information in checkout_submit_all_after event observer in Afterpay Payment Method Module. I am trying to add this event in that module.

File Path: **app/code/Afterpay/Afterpay/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento 2 extensions for Afterpay Payment
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="checkout_submit_all_after">
        <observer name="afterpay_save_order_after_submit" instance="Afterpay\Afterpay\Observer\SaveOrderAfterSubmitObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

File Path: **app/code/Afterpay/Afterpay/Observer/SaveOrderAfterSubmitObserver.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento 2 extensions for Afterpay Payment
 */
namespace Afterpay\Afterpay\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;

class SaveOrderAfterSubmitObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
    ) {
        $this->coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
    }

    /**
     * Save order into registry to use it in the overloaded controller.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /* @var $order Order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');
        $orderId = $order->getId();
        print_r($orderId); die('1');
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/testingObserver.log');

        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();

        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        $logger->info($orderId."OrderId");

    }
}
```

**I only want to use this event. I have checked several other questions where this event is not working but all the answers are asking to use different event. But I don't want to use any other event. Please help me to get work this event in Magento 2.**

Comment: Use all commands first setup:upgrade , di:compile and check,  still no log created then check https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/100198/magento-2-checkout-submit-all-after-event-is-not-working , https://mage2.pro/t/topic/822

Answer (score 1):

AfterPay placed order inside their own module which use **vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php**::**submit** and don't use **vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteManagement.php**::**placeOrder** method that actually fire: **checkout_submit_all_after** event. You can use **sales_model_service_quote_submit_success** instead.

For your case, just modify events.xml by the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento 2 extensions for Afterpay Payment
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_success">
        <observer name="afterpay_sales_model_service_quote_submit_success" instance="Afterpay\Afterpay\Observer\SaveOrderAfterSubmitObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```